# How can we log both user and bot messages to comos db in microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, logging, botframework

I have created a chat bot using microsoft bot framework v4 sdk. I wanted to log bot user and bot messages to cosmos db.

i am able to log only user messages using below blog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#using-cosmos-db .

I expect to log both user and bot responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thankfully, this is pretty easy since [ItranscriptLogger](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ITranscriptLogger.cs) and [TranscriptLoggerMiddleware](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs) already exist.

#### Create your TranscriptStore Class (new Class file)

```cs
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuickTestBot_CSharp
{
    public class CosmosTranscriptStore : ITranscriptLogger
    {
        private CosmosDbStorage _storage;

        public CosmosTranscriptStore(CosmosDbStorageOptions config)
        {
            _storage = new CosmosDbStorage(config);
        }
        public async Task LogActivityAsync(IActivity activity)
        {
            // activity only contains Text if this is a message
            var isMessage = activity.AsMessageActivity() != null ? true : false;
            if (isMessage)
            {
                // Customize this to save whatever data you want
                var data = new
                {
                    From = activity.From,
                    To = activity.Recipient,
                    Text = activity.AsMessageActivity().Text,
                };
                var document = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                // activity.Id is being used as the Cosmos Document Id
                document.Add(activity.Id, data);
                await _storage.WriteAsync(document, new CancellationToken());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Create and Add the Middleware (in Startup.cs)

```cs
[...]
var config = new CosmosDbStorageOptions
{
    AuthKey = "<YourAuthKey>",
    CollectionId = "<whateverYouWant>",
    CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri("https://<YourEndpoint>.documents.azure.com:443"),
    DatabaseId = "<whateverYouWant>",
};

var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new CosmosTranscriptStore(config));

var middleware = options.Middleware;
middleware.Add(transcriptMiddleware);
[...]
```

#### Result:

[image]

[image]

#### Note:

This is probably the easiest/best way to do it. However, you can also capture outgoing activities under `OnTurnAsync()` using `turnContext.OnSendActivities()` and then write the outgoing activity to storage, as well.

Comment: Need help registering middleware in startup.cs. This line says "options" does not exist in current context  - "var middleware = options.Middleware;"

Comment: @TomCat See if [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot/AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs) helps get you in the right direction. If not, post your own SO question, tag it with `botframework` and we'll help you out. It helps if we can see the code in your Startup.cs.

Comment: Thanks. Adding "Use(transcriptMiddlewareStore);" in the Adapter solved the issue.

Comment: I ended up using the OnSendActivities() method. This worked perfectly for our needs. [See here how to implement OnSendActivities()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390431/how-to-intercept-messages-in-bot-framework-v4-for-logging-using-c-sharp-core-3).