# Why does the trasncript logger/webBot store activity from the previous conversations after refreshing the webpage?

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

I am storing the chat transcript in Cosmos DB using ITranscriptLogger and TranscriptLoggerMiddleware. I am creating a new document with id equal to the conversation ID. When I refresh the webchat, it starts over and generates a new user ID and a new conversation ID.

The issue is that the new document/item in cosmos DB contains the chat transcript from all of the previous conversations in addition to the newest conversation. On top of that, all conversations with another user (on another computer) at work is stored in the same chat transcript, and is also piled on top of the previous conversations. Why is that? How can I store each conversation separately when I refresh the webpage, and more critical how can I separate the conversations with different users?

I have previously posted how I set up my storage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309498/11790679), and this is how the web chat is set up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
     ...
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="container" style="width: 370px; height: 500px; margin: 0; display:inline-block; ">
         <div id="header" style="
         background-color:#2f2f2f; height:30px; padding: 8px 8px 0 8px; font-weight: 500; font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif;
         color:#e3ce8e
         ">

         <span>MyBot</span></div>
          <div id="webchat" role = "main">
            </div>
       </div>

    <script>
    const groupTimestamp = 0;
      (async function () {
        const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers:
        { Authorization: 'SecretKeyFromAzureDirectLineSettings' } });
        const { token }  = await res.json();
        const styleOptions = {
         botAvatarImage: 'botPictureUrl',
         botAvatarInitials: 'PP',
         userAvatarImage: 'userPictureUrl',
         userAvatarInitials: 'PP',
         hideUploadButton: true,
         sendTypingIndicator: true,
       };
       const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
         if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
           dispatch({
             type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
             payload: {
               name: 'webchat/join',
               value: { language: window.navigator.language }
             }
           });
         }
         return next(action);
       });
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
        store,
        styleOptions,
        hideUploadButton: true,
        groupTimestamp: groupTimestamp,
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the user and bot responses to a list which was never cleared at the beginning of a new conversation, so that's the explanation to the problem. And the solution was simply clearing the list at the beginning of a new conversation...