# Bot Framework v4 c# - How to save entire chat conversation between user and chatbot

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I want to save entire conversation happened between user and chatbot in cosmos db.

I tried [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) but it only save the user data

and also tried using [ITranscriptLogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016335/how-can-we-log-both-user-and-bot-messages-to-comos-db-in-microsoft-bot-framework) but this is creating new item for each activity between user and bot

[image]

I want something like there should be one item created in cosmos db for specific user which has full conversation history between bot and user

Could any one let me know how can i do that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark mentioned it is not recommended to create just a single document to hold a conversation history.

[GetTranscriptActivitiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.azure.azureblobtranscriptstore.gettranscriptactivitiesasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) - This method pulls all the conversations. This brings all the activity that that is part of.
[image]

In  the above screenshot, you can see all the activities pertaining to the conversation.

**Just a thought -** You could iterate to each of them & you could combine them and save it in a single file.

Came across this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/8cb91cc83a53fd471637d4d6241baa89ffd76625/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/22.conversation-history/ConversationHistoryBot.cs) - here the entire conversation history sent back to the chat.

Comment: @nandini336 - just wanted to have quick check whether the above helped?

Answer (score 1):

I would not do that where you create just a single document to hold a conversation history as there is a 2MB limit for documents and also there is the possibility that the conversation history could be lost if the instance of bot framework crashed while holding the conversation history in memory.