# How to intercept messages in Bot Framework v4 for logging, using C# Core 3.1

Tags: c#, botframework, middleware, asp.net-core-3.1

We found this documentation explaining how to intercept messages in bot framework v3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

We want to do exactly that, only in v4 of the bot framework.

We could not find documentation for intercepting messages for bot framework v4 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Is there a way to intercept the messages in bot framework v4, so we can log them?

We do already log the user messages in the `OnMessageActivityAsync` method. So we only need to log the messages that are sent from the bot to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You  need the Middleware.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng any chance you could be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we tried creating our own middleware, but we could not get it to work.

After some more research we decided to use `turnContext.OnSendActivities` in the `MyBot.OnTurnAsync` method. Like this:

```
turnContext.OnSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, nextSend) =>
{
  // Log activities here
  return await nextSend();
});
```

For us this solution is perfect and way easier to implement then creating custom middleware. Thanks anyway.